# WorkerService deployed to Azure App Service is not starting

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm creating a new WorkerService in .NET Core 3.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and deploying it to Azure App Service.
In it it has nothing more then on Worker service which logs a message every 3 seconds.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Log.Information("Worker running");
            await Task.Delay(3000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm deploying it using Azure Release pipeline's Azure App Service deploy task.
Deployment goes through without any errors but the application is not starting. I know this because I check logs. Except logging in worker I also log application startup in `Program.cs`

When I navigate to console on Azure portal and start it with `dotnet Worker.dll` it starts and works fine. I see messages logged into blob container.

Do I need to do anything special for worker service? I was deploying .NET Core 3.1 web apps from Azure Release pipeline and I didn't have any problems.

**Edit:**

When published from VS2019 as Azure WebJob (this and folder are publish targets you can choose) it works as expected. However now it is visible in WebJobs blade. So this is different kind of deployment then from Azure Devops I think.

Comment: I create a simple workerservice and succeed to deploy to Azure web app through azure release pipeline. I followed  [Use Azure Portal to Verify Application is Working section of this blog](https://elanderson.net/2019/10/publish-a-net-core-worker-service-to-azure/) to check the logs and it worked as expected. Could you share the settings of build pipeline and release pipeline?

Comment: I'm using visual designer to create release pipeline so I'm not sure how I can share settings. I'm using Azure App Service deploy task. I switched to WebApi project and same release pipeline deployed application and it starts as expected.

Comment: A `run.cmd` script is necessary. Please check my answer to see if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, I suggest you write webjob apps with [WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs). The official way is to create a common console app, and then add functions.

Secondly, you need to add a `run.cmd` script in your webjob directory.

Here is a sample:

1. Add additional argument to publish to specific path in `Publish` dotnet task.

`--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebJob\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\WebJob`

[image]

2. Add a PowerShell task to generate `run.cmd` script

Important: Please ensure to set the right working directory as follwoing:

Script: `"dotnet WebJob.dll %*" | Out-File run.cmd -Encoding ASCII` , please change `WebJob.dll` to your dll name.

Working directory: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebJob\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\WebJob`

[image]

3. Publish the artifact

Path to publish: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebJob\`

[image]

4. If everything is OK, you will get an artifact after running build pipeline
   :

[image]

5. Create the release pipeline

Choose the right folder. Mine is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Webjob-ASP.NET Core-CI/drop`, you should change it with your correct folder path.

[image]

6. Check web app:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't want WebJob so I don't use WebJobs SDK. Will those steps work for worker service also?

Comment: Essentially, they are dlls. And, as you said it worked when you published as webjob in VS, you may check in portal with `Advanced Tools` (Kudu) to see how your WorkerService runs.  If your dll is under `app_data\Jobs\Continuous\WebJob` with a `run.cmd`, then this solution should be suitable for you.

Comment: hi all, can someone tells me whats the diff if i publish the Worker to Azure with or without 
UseWindowsService, both cases creates me a WebJob in Azure

Comment: Solid answer, helped me a lot in setting up webjob, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

To anyone still facing this and wants to avoid having to use WebJobs (including SDK) or paying for a VM etc..... All you need to do is go to your ****.csproj file for the project replace the second line from

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
```

to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Now you can deploy your worker service on App-Service and it will start automatically including on restarts etc. as if it's a web app. You will have to restrict network traffic etc. for security.

Comment: What needs to be replaced?

Comment: So change your project to a web project instead of a worker. No.